# Iterating Through Json with different keys

Tags: javascript, json

How would I go about looping through this JSON object to find a specific "id" key, and give back the name "outer key"? Sorry, I'm not too familiar with the proper name.

ie, search for the id '24', and get 'Jax' in Javascript?

```
{  
  "type":"champion",
  "version":"7.2.1",
  "data":{  
    "Jax":{  
      "id":24,
      "key":"Jax",
      "name":"Jax",
      "title":"Grandmaster at Arms",
      "tags":[  
        "Fighter",
        "Assassin"
      ]
    },
    "Sona":{  
      "id":37,
      "key":"Sona",
      "name":"Sona",
      "title":"Maven of the Strings",
      "tags":[  
        "Support",
        "Mage"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note, missing closing `}`.

Comment: Note, [there's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for..of` loop, `Object.entries()` to iterate property names and values of an object; if value `id` matches `24`, set variable to property name of that object; `break` loop or return property from within `if` statement.

```
function getData(json, _id) {
  let prop = `${_id} not found`;
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(json)) {
    let {id} = value;
    if (id && id === _id) {
      return key
    }
  }
  return prop;
}

let res = getData(json.data, 24);
```

Comment: Why wait for all the loop iterations to complete before returning?

Comment: @Phil Good point. Will include `break` within `if` statement.

Comment: or just `return key`

Comment: @Phil See updated post. Can further improvements be made?